# MTL framework. Create slideshow both with images and videos

Tags: mlt

Need to create images slideshow like here:
https://animeshnanda.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/how-to-make-a-slideshow-using-mlt-framework/

But i need also to add small videos between images.

```
melt 10.MOV \
11.MOV -mix 13 -mixer luma \
12.JPG -mix 13 -mixer luma -attach affine duration=4 transition.cycle=225 transition.geometry="0=0,0:100%x100%;74=-100,-100:120%x120%;75=-60,-60:110%x110%;149=0:0:110%x110%;150=0,-60:110%x110%;224=-60,0:110%x110%"
13.MOV -mix 13 -mixer luma \
-track music.mp3"
```

The problem is that image doesn't have transition and image duration lasts 4-5 minutes instead 4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the length parameter for your image.

```
12.JPG length=100
```

length is in number of frames. To convert that to time, you need to divide by the frame rate of your profile. Since you do not specify a profile in your example, melt will "guess" a profile based on your first clip. So the frame rate will be the same as 10.MOV.

Assuming a frame rate of 25fps, my example of length=100 would be 100/25 = 4 seconds. If your frame rate is 30fps, then use length=120 to get 4 seconds.

If you want the affine filter to only apply to the image, you need to move the filter definition to be immediately after the producer definition. Also, use -attach-clip to attach the filter only to the image producer. In this case, it would be:

```
12.JPG length=100 -attach-clip affine ... -mix 13 -mixer luma
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it helps, can you also help why transition is not running for image:

    melt 11.MOV 12.MOV -mix 13 -mixer luma 11.JPG length=100 -mix 13 -mixer luma -attach-clip crop center=1 -attach-clip affine transition.cycle=100 transition.geometry="74=-100,-100:120%x120%" -consumer avformat:test.mp4 vcodec=libx264 vb=3000k

Comment: Applied effects (crop and transition) lasts only when -mix 13 is running and than image reverts to it's original state...